# C++, How to replace multiple elements in an array

Tags: arrays, replace

I have two arrays in C++:

```
int A[]={2, 3, 5, 1, 4};
int B[]={2, 3, 5};
```

I want to replace 2 by 3, 3 by 5, and 5 by 2 in A.  These replacements are based on the elements in B.

After replacement, `A'` would be [3 5 2 1 4] (All replacements are inplace and simultaneous).

Edit: another example:

```
A = [ 2 5 3 1 9] ,       B = [3 2 1]
```

It means I must replace 3 by 2, 2 by 1 and 1 by 3  (see B)

```
The result is A'= [ 1 5 2 3 9]
```

Comment: Are these supposed to be variable declarations: A=[2 3 5 1 4], B=[2 -> 3 -> 5]. Could you more explicit about exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I mean B is equal to {2,3,5}. int B[] = {2,3,5}; The arrows show the way I want to replace the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what your code would look like :

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
for(j=0; j<2; j++)
   if (A[i] == B[j]){
       A[i] = B[j+1];
       break;
   }
```

Though it may not be the most efficient way to go about it.

Comment: Please see the new example. The first one seems ambiguous.

Comment: I have edited my previous answer and given you code for your problem in C++.

Comment: If size(A)=O(N) and size(B)=O(M), the runtime would be O(MN) in worst case. If any more efficient algorithm or data structure. In my case N may be about 5000000 and M is about 100~1000.

Comment: Not all elements are reqired to be replaced, this may make it possible to have a more efficient algorithm! But I'm not sure about it.

Comment: When I think of it that way my mind says "In order to find if the element has to be replaced or not you will have to compare it anyways with all elements in B." Though I wouldn't be surprised if it turns out that I am wrong.

Comment: If I use a bit vector to indicate if the element is in B, I can reduce the runtime (at least in practice). Isn't it?

Comment: It would be better if you coded some part of that and added it as an edit to your question. That way others could work on it.

Comment: this code has a bug. if j = 2, j + 1 = 3, B[j+1] will cause out of bound exception. So for the second loop, the limit should be j < 2;

Answer (score 2):

you may want to check out std::rotate (first, middle, end); So you code will be something like

```
    std::rotate(A, A+1, A+3);
```

The link is

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate

Comment: 2 -> 3 -> 5   is based on the second Matrix, not necessarily consecutive elements in A. I am adding another example